# Pra que serve a função uneval?

Tags: javascript

Eu estava vendo alguma coisas no Javascript (que pra mim parecem novidade) e acabei me deparando com um exemplo que mostrava uma função chamada `uneval`.

Algumas dúvidas abaixo sobre ela:

- Essa função é nova no Javascript (estamos em 2018)?
- Ela faz o "contrário" de `eval`?
- Li também que ela não deve ser usada em produção. Usar ela traz algum risco para minha aplicação?
- Ela funciona em quais navegadores?

Comment: Para nada. Próxima? Ao que parece, ela representa em *string* a definição de um objeto que, se utilizada com o `eval`, o reconstrói. Sinceramente, não consigo pensar em aplicação alguma disso. Talvez exista apenas por uma necessidade interna, visto que nem é especificada.

Comment: Você só consegue testar esse método no Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: [uneval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/uneval) método escrito por um estagiário da Mozilla. be careful.

Comment: Tem uma aplicação nesse link http://www.htmlstaff.org/ver.php?id=26934 Como dito anteriormente, só funciona no Firefox

Comment: Porquê os negativos ? Parece-me uma pergunta razoável.

Comment: Quem deu negativo tem alguma justificativa razoável?

Comment: Na documentação tá _deprecated_

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo eu só vi uma coisa de anexar arrays, nada relativo ao uso do `eval`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Resposta**: para nada prático.

Dado o conteúdo na internet, acredito que a função `uneval` tenha sido criada pela equipe da Mozilla sob alguma demanda interna e acabaram por deixando a função ali - quem sabe o Firefox até use ela para alguma coisa.

## Compatibilidade

Ela é, de fato, exclusiva do Firefox e não está prevista em nenhuma especificação corrente, então não nenhum tipo de previsão ou sequer se discute implementá-la em outros navegadores, então, na prática, ela realmente não terá utilidade alguma - a menos que você tenha uma aplicação que rode exclusivamente no Firefox, tal como uma extensão do navegador, por exemplo.

[image: Compatibilidade da função uneval no deskyop]

No mobile não é diferente.

[image: Compatibilidade da funcao uneval no mobile]

## Função

Mas o que ela faz? Bom, de forma simplificada, ela faz o inverso da função [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). Enquanto o `eval` constrói um objeto a partir de sua representação como *string*, a função `uneval` constrói uma *string* que representa um objeto. Por exemplo, ao fazer `uneval(function foo(){});` o retorno será a *string* `"(function foo(){})"` e, sendo uma *string*, você pode fazer qualquer coisa que pode ser feito com uma *string*: exibí-la no *console*, enviar via HTTP, etc. No PHP, existe a função [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.var-export.php) que possui função bastante semelhante.

Por exemplo, você poderia mostrar o código fonte de uma função no `console.log`, junto com uma mensagem de erro, para facilitar o *debug* ou até alimentar algum outro tipo de *log* - estejam cientes que existem inúmeras maneiras melhores de se fazer isso, então não façam assim:

> **Nota:** o exemplo abaixo só funcionará no Firefox pelos motivos supracitados.

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
    throw "Desculpe, sei apenas somar números";
  }
  
  return a + b;
}

try {
  const result = sum(2, 'a');
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Falha na função sum(a, b):', error);
  console.log( uneval(sum) );
}
```

Assim, a saída no *console* seria:

```
Falha na função sum(a, b): Desculpe, sei apenas somar números
function sum(a, b) {
  if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
    throw "Desculpe, sei apenas somar números";
  }

  return a + b;
}
```

Mas, convenhamos, nem é uma aplicação tão útil assim.

## E o método `Object.prototype.toString`?

Ambas parecem fazer a mesma coisa: retornar a representação em *string* de um objeto, porém, o método `toString` não se preocupa em gerar uma *string* que seja um código JavaScript válido, enquanto a `uneval` sim. Se tomar a representação de ambas de um objeto JS fica fácil perceber a diferença:

```
const obj = new Object()

console.log(obj.toString())  // [object Object]
console.log(uneval(obj))  // ({})
```

Para demonstrar a validade do código JavaScript, basta aplicar a função `eval`:

```
console.log( eval(obj.toString()) )  // Erro
console.log( eval(uneval(obj)) ) // Object {  }
```

Embora a combinação `eval`+`uneval` recria o objeto, não significa que serão o mesmo objeto.

```
obj == eval(uneval(obj))  // false
```

Comment: `uneval(algo)` da na mesma que `algo.toString()`?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Não. Embora pareçam ser, o método `toString` não se preocupa em criar uma representação do objeto que seja código JavaScript válido. Por exemplo, pode fazer `obj = new Object()`; ao fazer `obg.toString()` você obtém `[object Object]`, enquanto no `uneval` obtém `({})`.

Comment: E `algo.valueOf()`?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam o `valueOf` é completamente diferente e nem cabe nesta comparação :D

Comment: valeu, no último código escreveu `evan`

Comment: Você respondeu muito bem e falou justamente da parte de interesse, eu ia responder, mas acho que a sua esta tão boa que vou lhe indicar outra coisa que acho interessante citar sobre o non-starndard 'ligado' a isto: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource